# How to stop Sequelize to drop existing table?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am creating a application in nodejs using express.js ,I need to connect Oracle db, I am using Sequelize ORM framework for that,I created model and tried to access db,it dropped existing table and created new table, I have lost my data,how to stop dropping table and make sync with existing table and data using Sequelize orm?

Comment: Can we see the sequelize.js code you use to connect to the DB?

Comment: sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  ...called if successful...
}, function(err) {
  ...called if an error occurred...
});

Answer (score 6):

Set **force : false**
When force is true it's mean you are allowing sequelize to drop existing tables and create new ones.

```
sequelize.sync({
  force: false,
}).then(() => {
        // your code 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont call

```
sequelize.sync()
```

Only connect to the db directly, sync will drop the db, I wont recommend using sync for automated db migration,  instead use sequelize migration for systematic db migrations.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname');
```

Comment: Without sync() ,how to use models?

Answer (score 0):

Models are automatically mapped, you just need to define them . You can use  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto to generate model files from db directly and then define associations as required

Comment: Can I use Sequelize-auto for Oracle?,I am not able to see  dialect options for Oracle

Comment: officially it doesnt, there is this pulgin https://github.com/adeo-proxideco/sequelize-oracle you can try, havent used it personally

Comment: I am using this plugin only ,if this is not official one, please tell me which is best orm framework work for connecting Oracle db using nodejs( should be ORM framework), I have searched lot in internet, I was not able to find a good one

Comment: Cant help you out with that, dont know if there are any better plugins for Oracle Db